# deploying sharepoint hosted app run into security prompt

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I wrote a very simple sharepoint hosted app (2013). I kept getting a lot of windows credential prompt, asking for domain user name and password when I tried to deploy to my development server.

I have a separated app domain setup.  Also, from the vs2013 deploying output, it shows the app successfully deployed to my hosted web.

When I go to the site (hosted web), I can see the link of my app is appearing on the left hand nav panel, inside of the Recent section..  However, when I click on the link again, the windows security prompts and asking for my network credential. I kept entering it, but it just kept prompting...

My app url is: app-47294dea293202.appDomainName.com usually if this is my regular IIS web, I will go and check the IIS authentication and try to enable/disable the anonymous/windows login, but in this kind of url, where I can go and tweak that?

I have been trying to fix this issue for many hours, I felt really exhausted working with Sharepoint 2013..

Answer (score 0):

Open Internet Explorer -> Internet Options -> Tab Security -> Local Intranet -> Click Sites -> Advanced -> Add the link http(or https) ://*.appDomainName.com.

This is append because the url is not recognize as Local Intranet and IE doesn't pass the current credentials, check also:

Internet Explorer -> Internet Options -> Tab Advanced -> Under Security Group -> Enable Integrated Windows Authentication is checked (This options pass the current credentials on Local Intranet Site).

You can try also the [Disable the loopback check](http://blogs.technet.com/b/sharepoint_foxhole/archive/2010/06/21/disableloopbackcheck-lets-do-it-the-right-way.aspx)